# How to handle Socket accept failed Error is coming In in Jsp Project

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

```
Sep 4, 2013 9:59:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor run
SEVERE: Socket accept failed
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:470)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:438)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I have deploy my Jsp Application in Linux base tomcat server and log file coming its size approx 11 Gb i dont know how to Handle this What i have to do to fix for this please help am totally new in this Error its developer work some thing Else. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are leaking file handles or sockets. Check your closes.